# Bind paper-toggle-button label to its checked state - Polymer

Tags: html, polymer

Is there any way to bind the label of a `paper-toggle-button` to its checked state?

ie. if the toggle button is unchecked it will have a label = "false", and if checked will read "true"

Any thoughts and hints will be appreciated.

**Edit**

I should mention that the above is a generalised question, but my needs are a little more specific as I shall explain.

I have toggle buttons that are bound to either on/off by true/false data brought in via ajax and JSON data. Therefore, Ben's answer below although correct, I don't think can help me in this situation.

***My toggle code***

```
<div class="item horizontal layout">
    <div class="heading">Approver: </div>
    <paper-toggle-button checked$="{{response.approver}}">{{response.approver}}</paper-toggle-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the `checked` state to a property and then observe this property for changes. When it changes, you can then update the label text.

For example, bind a property to the checked property and get the label text from a property:

```
<paper-toggle-button checked="{{toggle}}">{{labelText}}</paper-toggle-button>
```

Then in the JavaScript section, you declare the `toggle` property and give it an observer. In the observer, we check the value of the property and update the label text accordingly:

```
Polymer({
  is: "x-test",
  properties: {
    toggle: {
      type: Boolean,
      observer: '_toggleChange'
    }
  },
  _toggleChange: function (newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      this.labelText = "True";
    } else {
      this.labelText = "";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for the info. The question above was a more general one surrounding this topic. I actually have a toggle-button that is already bound to an ajax request for user data so I currently have code like this...........<paper-toggle-button checked$="{{response.isSystemManager}}">{{labelText}}</paper-toggle-button>............ is there any way you could see me retrofitting your answer to this? I tried using the same "response." bit in the label but of course, it doesn't change when you switch the toggle.

Comment: Yes, have a look at [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#observing-path-changes) which tells you how to observe changes to sub-properties.

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for the pointer. Is there any way you could show me how in a JSFiddle or something? Not trying to be cheeky, I'm just not comfortable with listeners and things like that. And I don't like the official documentation XD

Comment: Use this.set('response.approver', true) to update the subproperty, and do that in the AJAX response method.